# Does your strength modifier impact your ability to draw weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Our DM has a rule that if your Strength modifier is -1 or lower, drawing your weapon is a full-round action. If you have a neutral or positive strength modifier, drawing your weapon would become a quick action. However, none of the research I have done supports this. Is this an actual rule, and (if so) where could I find it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The particular rule you've given is a house rule. Strength does not affect a character's ability to draw their weapon. However, the rules for drawing or sheathing a weapon state,

> If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher, you may draw a weapon as a free action combined with a regular move.

Source: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#draworSheatheaWeapon

Therefore, characters with a BAB of 0 would have to spend a *move action* to draw their weapon. Characters with a BAB higher than 0 can take a free action to draw a weapon as long as they also take a regular movement action that round.

Comment: It could've been a misunderstanding of the rules.

Answer (score 12):

## This is a house rule

It is unsupported by any text. I can imagine in this universe any reasonably intelligent low-Strength creature simply carries its weapon unsheathed all the time, rendering such a house rule largely—*ahem*—pointless.